# WordPress Multiple Gravity Forms on Single Page is not working

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

In a Home Page i have to use same gravity form shortcode on difference section of the pages.But Once one form is submitted then it affect also on the form.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code to your theme functions.php

```
<?php 
class Gravity_Forms_Multiple_Form_Instances { 
 
    /** 
     * Constructor. 
     *     
     * Used to initialize the plugin and hook the related functionality. 
     * 
     * @access public 
     */ 
    public function __construct() { 
        // hook the HTML ID string find & replace functionality 
        add_filter( 'gform_get_form_filter', array( $this, 'gform_get_form_filter_multiple' ), 10, 2 ); 
    } 
 
    /** 
     * Replaces all occurences of the form ID with a new, unique ID. 
     *     
     * This is where the magic happens. 
     * 
     * @access public 
     * 
     * @param string $form_string The form HTML string. 
     * @param array $form Array with the form settings. 
     * @return string $form_string The modified form HTML string. 
     */ 
    public function gform_get_form_filter_multiple( $form_string, $form ) { 
        // if form has been submitted, use the submitted ID, otherwise generate a new unique ID 
        if ( isset( $_POST['gform_random_id'] ) ) { 
            $random_id = absint( $_POST['gform_random_id'] ); // Input var okay. 
        } else { 
            $random_id = mt_rand();     
        } 
 
        // this is where we keep our unique ID 
        $hidden_field = "<input type='hidden' name='gform_field_values'"; 
 
        // define all occurences of the original form ID that wont hurt the form input 
        $strings = array( 
            ' gform_wrapper ' => ' gform_wrapper gform_wrapper_original_id_' . $form['id'] . ' ',  
            "for='choice_" => "for='choice_" . $random_id . '_',  
            "id='choice_" => "id='choice_" . $random_id . '_',  
            "id='gform_target_page_number_" => "id='gform_target_page_number_" . $random_id . '_',
            "id='gform_source_page_number_" => "id='gform_source_page_number_" . $random_id . '_',
            "#gform_target_page_number_"  => "#gform_target_page_number_" . $random_id . '_',
            "#gform_source_page_number_"  => "#gform_source_page_number_" . $random_id . '_',    
            "id='label_" => "id='label_" . $random_id . '_',  
            "'gform_wrapper_" . $form['id'] . "'" => "'gform_wrapper_" . $random_id . "'",  
            "'gf_" . $form['id'] . "'" => "'gf_" . $random_id . "'",  
            "'gform_" . $form['id'] . "'" => "'gform_" . $random_id . "'",  
            "'gform_ajax_frame_" . $form['id'] . "'" => "'gform_ajax_frame_" . $random_id . "'",  
            '#gf_' . $form['id'] . "'" => '#gf_' . $random_id . "'",  
            "'gform_fields_" . $form['id'] . "'" => "'gform_fields_" . $random_id . "'",  
            "id='field_" . $form['id'] . '_' => "id='field_" . $random_id . '_',  
            "for='input_" . $form['id'] . '_' => "for='input_" . $random_id . '_',  
            "id='input_" . $form['id'] . '_' => "id='input_" . $random_id . '_',  
            "'gform_submit_button_" . $form['id'] . "'" => "'gform_submit_button_" . $random_id . "'",  
            '"gf_submitting_' . $form['id'] . '"' => '"gf_submitting_' . $random_id . '"',  
            "'gf_submitting_" . $form['id'] . "'" => "'gf_submitting_" . $random_id . "'",  
            '#gform_ajax_frame_' . $form['id'] => '#gform_ajax_frame_' . $random_id,  
            '#gform_wrapper_' . $form['id'] => '#gform_wrapper_' . $random_id,  
            '#gform_' . $form['id'] => '#gform_' . $random_id,  
            "trigger('gform_post_render', [" . $form['id'] => "trigger('gform_post_render', [" . $random_id,  
            'gformInitSpinner( ' . $form['id'] . ', ' => 'gformInitSpinner( ' . $random_id . ', ',  
            "trigger('gform_page_loaded', [" . $form['id'] => "trigger('gform_page_loaded', [" . $random_id,  
            "'gform_confirmation_loaded', [" . $form['id'] . ']' => "'gform_confirmation_loaded', [" . $random_id . ']',  
            'gf_apply_rules(' . $form['id'] . ', ' => 'gf_apply_rules(' . $random_id . ', ',  
            'gform_confirmation_wrapper_' . $form['id'] => 'gform_confirmation_wrapper_' . $random_id,  
            'gforms_confirmation_message_' . $form['id'] => 'gforms_confirmation_message_' . $random_id,  
            'gform_confirmation_message_' . $form['id'] => 'gform_confirmation_message_' . $random_id,  
            'if(formId == ' . $form['id'] . ')' => 'if(formId == ' . $random_id . ')',  
            "window['gf_form_conditional_logic'][" . $form['id'] . ']' => "window['gf_form_conditional_logic'][" . $random_id . ']',  
            "trigger('gform_post_conditional_logic', [" . $form['id'] . ', ' => "trigger('gform_post_conditional_logic', [" . $random_id . ', ',  
            'gformShowPasswordStrength("input_' . $form['id'] . '_' => 'gformShowPasswordStrength("input_' . $random_id . '_',  
            "gformInitChosenFields('#input_" . $form['id'] . '_' => "gformInitChosenFields('#input_" . $random_id . '_',  
            "jQuery('#input_" . $form['id'] . '_' => "jQuery('#input_" . $random_id . '_',  
            'gforms_calendar_icon_input_' . $form['id'] . '_' => 'gforms_calendar_icon_input_' . $random_id . '_',  
            "id='ginput_base_price_" . $form['id'] . '_' => "id='ginput_base_price_" . $random_id . '_',  
            "id='ginput_quantity_" . $form['id'] . '_' => "id='ginput_quantity_" . $random_id . '_',  
            'gfield_price_' . $form['id'] . '_' => 'gfield_price_' . $random_id . '_',  
            'gfield_quantity_' . $form['id'] . '_' => 'gfield_quantity_' . $random_id . '_',  
            'gfield_product_' . $form['id'] . '_' => 'gfield_product_' . $random_id . '_',  
            'ginput_total_' . $form['id'] => 'ginput_total_' . $random_id,  
            'GFCalc(' . $form['id'] . ', ' => 'GFCalc(' . $random_id . ', ',  
            'gf_global["number_formats"][' . $form['id'] . ']' => 'gf_global["number_formats"][' . $random_id . ']',  
            'gform_next_button_' . $form['id'] . '_' => 'gform_next_button_' . $random_id . '_',  
            'gform_previous_button_' . $form['id'] . '_' => 'gform_previous_button_' . $random_id . '_',  
            $hidden_field => "<input type='hidden' name='gform_random_id' value='" . $random_id . "' />" . $hidden_field,  
 ); 
 
        // allow addons & plugins to add additional find & replace strings 
        $strings = apply_filters( 'gform_multiple_instances_strings', $strings ); 
 
        // replace all occurences with the new unique ID 
        foreach ( $strings as $find => $replace ) { 
            $form_string = str_replace( $find, $replace, $form_string ); 
        } 
 
        return $form_string; 
    } 
 
} 

// initialize the plugin
global $gravity_forms_multiple_form_instances;
$gravity_forms_multiple_form_instances = new Gravity_Forms_Multiple_Form_Instances(); ?>
```

Answer (score -2):

Please use Gravity Form : Multiple Instance Add On Plugin
https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-gf-form-on-single-page/

Comment: Your plugin doesn't work. It throws a JS error after submission because it wants to scroll to a non-existing DOM element.